# C# Problem sending post httpwebrequest with 'input type image'

Tags: c#

I am sending a post request by HttpWebRequest. There is a element which is a input type=image. There is no other value of this element. But when I sending request with browser it is adding a .x and .y value into it. But in source page I cant find it. Here is the element

```
<input type="image" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvResults$ctl02$ibImg" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvResults_ctl02_ibImg" src="images/image.gif" alt="Document Image: 128 Pages" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvResults$ctl02$ibImg&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" style="height:16px;width:13px;border-width:0px;">
```

I am tracking it with a sniffer tool. And It is sending post data like that

```
&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24gvResults%24ctl02%24ibImg.x=3&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24gvResults%24ctl02%24ibImg.y=12
```

I hope I make my self clear. Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/p/input-image-tag.htm

> The image INPUT tag uses an image as
>   an input fields. The image can be used
>   as a submit button (with a script to
>   submit the form onclick) or to collect
>   data from the image itself (similar to
>   an image map, but in a form). **The
>   browser will submit the coordinates
>   where the user clicked on the image**.

**bold added by me for emphasis**

Comment: so is that means I can send any coordinates as x and y as I am sending request via HttpWebRequest?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that with the WebRequest object...  Go ahead and try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

That is by design. The browser is adding those extra post variables.

[In HTML forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1), an input of type image will send the x and y coordinates where the mouse clicked on the image along with the post. This was commonly done to implement server-side image maps.

Comment: Where would the x,y coordinates go?  Maybe in my postData (ASCII.GetBytes(postData))?  Here is the ojbect I'm trying to submit a username and password against.  <input type="image" name="Submit" id="Submit" class="LoginSubmit" onclick="Validate();" />  I'm not sure this is possible.